# How to display values in numbers instead of precentages in Plotly Pie chart?

Tags: python, plotly, pie-chart

Is there a way to display the actual values instead of percentage on the plotly pie chart?

Below is the sample code which is a part of views.py file. The graph variable is then passed to HTML file to display the interactive image generated from plotly.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
def my_view(request):

    esd = df.groupby('ProjectStatus', as_index=False).agg({"ProjectID": "count"})
    fig = px.pie(esd, values=Tasks, names=my_labels, color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.Blugrn)
    graph = fig.to_html(full_html=False, default_height=350, default_width=500)
    context = {'graph': graph}
```

The above would generate the attached pie chart. The values mentioned on hover should be displayed inside pie chart or on tooltip.

[Pie chart generated from above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0a8Q.png)

Comment: Hi Rishabh Aher, there is no need to share all the sql connection and query.

Comment: Hi rpanai, I have removed the sql connection and query part. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are a `fig.update_traces` away from your expected output.

```py
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.pie(df, values='tip', names='day')
# You should add this
fig.update_traces(hoverinfo='label+percent', textinfo='value')
fig.show()
```